# Laravel Passport Authorize page not redirecting to callback after submit

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I have a Laravel 8 app (upgraded from 6.4) with Laravel Passport. I'm trying to connect it to Zapier with Oauth2. I followed the steps from the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport.

[Capture of my authorization page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Twz.png)

When I click on "Authorize" nothing happens. I can see in the database that the auth code has been created but the page is not redirecting to the callback url. What is missing here?

Comment: Any solution on this?